# silver light datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

Iam new to silverlight so i need help from your side. my query is one page haivng the datagrid,that datagrid have only 6 columns.after 6 columns their is a scape so that scape showing itself one column.so i avoid that column in datagrid.scape may be show with out the column this is my query.
it is urgent for me.please resolve the solution as possible as early.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase?

Comment: I have a compilation error: `scape` is undefined. Without knowing what you are talking about no-one can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no idea what a 'scape' is, what you need to do is start out by creating a 'display' class that inherits from IEditable and INotify. For example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Application.Views.DisplayClasses
{
    public class DisplayClass : IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

       //Create private vars
        private string a;
        private string b;
        private string c;
        private string d;
        private bool e;


        // Create public properties with meta data to tell the grid to display and what order etc
        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
        public string A
        {
            get { return a; }
            set { a = value; }
        }

        [Display(Order = 0, Name = "B", AutoGenerateField = true)]
        public string B
        {
            get { return b; }
            set { b = value; }
        }

        [Display(Order = 1, Name = "C", AutoGenerateField = true)]
        public String C
        {
            get { return c; }
            set { c= value; }
        }

        [Display(Order = 2, Name = "D", AutoGenerateField = true)]
        public string D
        {
            get { return d; }
            set { d = value; }
        }

        [Display(Order = 2, Name = "E", AutoGenerateField = true)]
        public string E
        {
            get { return e; }
            set { e = value; }
        }

        #region IEditableObject Members

        public void BeginEdit()
        {

        }

        public void CancelEdit()
        {

        }

        public void EndEdit()
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null))
            {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Then you need to create an ObservableCollection to store the data your getting back from the database in:

```
    // Code to get data from the database (from your webservice)

//Make this Observable collection global
public static ObservableCollection<DisplayClass> ItemList = new ObservableCollection<DisplayClass>();

// In your oncompleted event method, put something similar to the following code
foreach (var DatabaseItem in DataFromMyWebService)
{
    DisplayClass GridItem = new DisplayClass();

    GridItem.A = DatabaseItem.A;
    GridItem.B = DatabaseItem.B;
    GridItem.C = DatabaseItem.C;
    GridItem.D = DatabaseItem.D;

    ItemList.Add(GridItem);
}

dgDataGrid.ItemsSource = ItemList;
```

You want to make your observable collection global so that if you need to change an item in your collection, the datagrid will automatically display those changes. Notice the meta data ([]) in the display class. That is how you control which properties are displayed and in what order. You will also want to set the property 'AutoGenerate="True"' in your datagrid element in your XAML code.